# Where/how did this menu-bar application implant itself?

Tags: menu-bar, login-items

After installing a given application that shows an icon in the menu bar, I would like to delete it. A `sudo rm -fr /Applications/foobar.app`, followed by a reboot, is insufficient; the menu bar application runs again. And I don't see it running among my login items in the first place.

[image: list of login items]

Might the app be lurking in `~/Library`? Apparently not. Only a database and log files are there.

```
> find ~/Library -name "foobar" -print
Library/Application Support/foobar
Library/Logs/foobar
```

Where might such an app have implanted itself, and how does it run at startup when it does not appear among the `Login items`?

**Update**

This behavior has been changed in High Sierra. A widget that positions itself in the menu-bar does not survive, even though it needs sudo permission before doing so. The permission is needed again.

Comment: tbh, Googling "uninstall xyz" before trying to manually delete any app that has to hook up low in the OS would have been a better first approach. Re-install followed by correct uninstall would be simplest now.

Comment: @Tetsujin Please read my last comment for the reasoning behind manual deletion. And it's not just the suspicion of nefarious applications. When upgrading the OS, an application may cease to work. Since Apple has updated the OS in-place for years, we all have many files (plist and others) sitting unused. It would be nice to clean up (once every 5 years) with some confidence that nothing will break.

Comment: Hmm... a question that is so intensely disliked cannot be deleted. Interesting.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall iStat Menus, please choose iStat Menus > Uninstall from the menubar, then click Uninstall. This works, even if your trial period is over. I think the uninstall process from iStat Menu themselves will do a lot more then only deleting the app itself.

[image: Uninstall iStat Menu]

You can also find the uninstaller in Macintosh HD > Library > Application Support > iStat local > Uninstaller.app

Or delete:

- Library > LauchAgents > com.bjango.istatlocal.plist
- Library > LaunchDaemons > com.bjango.istatlocaldaemon.plist

So far the iStat Menu specific part. More general information:

Deleting the app alone is not enough. There are LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, Preferences, Applications Support folders, Cache etc which also needs to be deleted to remove an application completely.

Comment: I'm really hoping for a more general answer. What if there is concern a given application is nefarious. There must be a way for someone to go to the Terminal and remove the application. Why is deleting `/Applications/foobar` insufficient to delete the application?

Comment: I improved my answer already a bit. In LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons you can find the apps/process that start automatically. For the one who down voted me.. how can I improve my answer more?

Comment: @calaf the general answer would be to analyze all files installed - not everything is installed in /Applications

Comment: OK, that worked. (My real problem was figuring out what triggered a modem-like noise that I could only hear in the dead of night. Deleting every trace of the app manually is my a-little-bit-paranoidal way of ensuring it's gone.) Recipe:  1- Delete /Applications/foobar, 2- Delete /Library/Application Support/foobar, 3- reboot, 4- Browse /Library/LaunchAgents and delete any foobar entries, 5- Repeat for /Library/LaunchDaemons